# Environment color within mdframed change after page break

Tags: color, page-breaking, mdframed

I am creating teaching notes with examples and solutions. At the begining of the course, I provide to the students the lecture notes with the examples but blank solutions so they can fill the box during class as I do the example in class. After the class I upload the examples with solutions.

I am planing to do that with the `mdframed` package. I define my `mdframed` and write the exercise question, then I add a solution (exsolution) environment within the `mdframed` which I set the color to be white when I do not want the students to see the solutions or black when I want them to see the solutions.

The problem comes with page breaks where the color in the solution does not follow after the page break. Any feedback?

I am adding an example when I set the solution color `\ColourOfSolutions` to be white:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcounter{example}
 \renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}
 \newcommand{\ColourOfSolutions}{white}

\mdfdefinestyle{example}{%
    linecolor=black,
    outerlinewidth=1.5pt,
    %bottomline=false,
    %leftline=false,rightline=false,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
    frametitle=\mbox{},
    fontcolor=black
}

\newmdenv[%
style=example,
settings={\global\refstepcounter{example}},
frametitlefont={\bfseries Example~\theexample\quad},
]{example}

\newenvironment{exsolution}{\color{\ColourOfSolutions}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[3]

    \begin{exsolution}
    \lipsum[4]
    \lipsum[5]
    \end{exsolution}

\end{example}   

\end{document}
```

Please find here the image of what I get. Please check that the solution is white, does not appear, in the first page but appears again (the last part of the solution) in the second page. changing the `\ColourOfSolutions` to black would illustrate this better:

[image]
[image]

I have seen many cases of people working with examples and solutions but I have not seen anything similar.

Comment: If you are open to use `lualatex`, you could use `\usepackage{luacolor}` and the colour stack will be maintained during pagebreakings

Comment: There's also `pdfcol` package, but it does not work (I'll try to figure out)

Comment: A solution without `lualatex` would also be nice

Comment: I was using PDFLatex. This is part of a biger document and Yes i can run the whole document it with LuaTex but need to clean it and modify thing that seems not to work nicely with LuaTex. However yes a solution without lualatex would be very nice.

Comment: Are there still no solutions for `mdframed`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the question was about `mdframed`, may be you can consider `tcolorbox` as an alternative solution. Next code doesn't show an `example` environment as complete as your one (see update), but a partial example which shows that the color problem doesn't appear with breakable tcolorboxes.

In this case, the example form the `upperbox` while solutions are the `lowerbox`. With parameter `lowerbox=visible|invisible` you can decide if lower box is printed or not.

You don't need to change to `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcounter{example}
 \renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}
 \newcommand{\ColourOfSolutions}{white}

\newtcolorbox{example}{enhanced,breakable,lowerbox=invisible,collower=blue}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[3]

%All solutions are into the `lowerbox`
    \tcblower

    \lipsum[4]
    \lipsum[5]
\end{example}   

\end{document}
```

With an `invisible` lower box:

[image]

and with a `visible` one:

[image]

*Update: Format similar to OP's box*

Just to show how to reproduce a format similar to what OP posted with `tcolorbox`. The code, adapted from example in pages 55-56 in `tcolorbox` documentation, could be something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcounter{example}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=example]{example}{%
    empty,
    title={Example \thetcbcounter},
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, left=3mm, top=2mm},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\smallskip\noindent,
    parbox=false,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=3mm,
    right=3mm,
    top=4pt,
    breakable,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    overlay unbroken={%
        \draw[line width=2pt] ([yshift=1pt]title.north west) rectangle 
            (frame.south east);},
    overlay first={%
        \draw[line width=2pt]([xshift=1pt]frame.south west) |- 
            ([yshift=1pt]title.north)-|([xshift=-1pt]frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={%
        \draw[line width=2pt]([xshift=1pt]frame.south west) -- 
            ([xshift=1pt]frame.north west);
        \draw[line width=2pt]([xshift=-1pt]frame.south east) -- 
            ([xshift=-1pt]frame.north east);},
    overlay last={%
        \draw[line width=2pt]([xshift=1pt]frame.north west) |- 
            (frame.south)-|([xshift=-1pt]frame.north east);},
    vfill before first,
    lowerbox=visible,
    collower=blue,
    }

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[4]

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[3]
%All solutions are into the `lowerbox`
    \tcblower
    \lipsum[4]
\end{example}   

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[3]
%All solutions are into the `lowerbox`
    \tcblower
    \lipsum[4]
\end{example}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is cheating ;-) Using a different setup where the colour stack isn't affected ;-) (+1)

Comment: Many thanks Ignasi!
It does work quite nicely and I did adopt it already. I was adapting your initial post to my format before replying... but then I see that you have done it already. Thank you!
tcolorbox provides a nice solution in this case. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

If `lualatex` is no obstacle `\usepackage{luacolor}` will preserve the colour stacks. (I changed the colour however to `blue` to make it more outstanding for this example)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{luacolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcounter{example}
 \renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}
 \newcommand{\ColourOfSolutions}{blue}

\mdfdefinestyle{example}{%
    linecolor=black,
    outerlinewidth=1.5pt,
    %bottomline=false,
    %leftline=false,rightline=false,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
    frametitle=\mbox{},
    fontcolor=black
}

\newmdenv[%
style=example,
settings={\global\refstepcounter{example}},
frametitlefont={\bfseries Example~\theexample\quad},
]{example}

\newenvironment{exsolution}{\color{\ColourOfSolutions}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[3]

    \begin{exsolution}
    \lipsum[4]
    \lipsum[5]
    \end{exsolution}

\end{example}   

\end{document}
```

[image]