# thmtools drops font coloring at page break when paired with mdframed

Tags: pdftex, color, environments, page-breaking, thmtools

Right now, I use `thmtools` with `mdframed` to create theorem environments with lines down the side. The difficulty is that I also want to be able to change the color of the text in these theorem environments. The issue is that defining this color using the expected method (a `\color{}` call in the `bodyfont` parameter) has a bug: it cuts off at page break.

[image]

Style:

```
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{lemmaTitle!80!black}, 
    bodyfont=\itshape\color{lemmaBody},
    mdframed={
        linewidth=1pt,
        rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
        linecolor=lemmaTitle, backgroundcolor=pageColor,
    }
]{lemmabox}
```

Declaration:

```
\declaretheorem[
    style=lemmabox,
    name=Lemma,
    parent=section,
    sibling=definition,
]{lemma}
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? In case it matters, as it seems to matter for questions similar to this one (but for other packages) I'm using `pdflatex` as the distribution (in particular, not `luatex` or `xelatex`), and `xcolor` for handling color. I've tried wrapping the environment or the entire page in a `tcolorbox` that allows for color stacking, but this creates a whole host of other issues (and doesn't really fix the problem).

Minimal example demonstrating issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{blue}, 
    bodyfont=\itshape\color{red},
    mdframed={linewidth=1pt, rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false, linecolor=green}
]{lemmabox}
\declaretheorem[style=lemmabox, name=Lemma]{lemma}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{40em}
\begin{lemma}[Test]
    Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. 
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that displays the issue

Comment: @mbert, thanks for the note. Added a minimal (nonworking) example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268917/environment-color-within-mdframed-change-after-page-break

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using tcolorbox's `\tcolorboxenvironment` command with the `use color stack` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{blue}, 
    bodyfont=\itshape\color{red}
]{lemmabox}
\declaretheorem[style=lemmabox, name=Lemma]{lemma}

\tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    left=5mm,
    before skip=10pt,
    after skip=10pt,
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{green},
    pad before break=2pt,
    pad after break=2pt,
    use color stack,
    }

\begin{document}

\vspace*{42em}

\begin{lemma}[Test]
    Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The options were mostly copied from section 18.4 of the [tcolorbox manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).